# SQL If condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have a table called `Train` with this sample data:

```
train_id strt_stn_id  end_stn_id    direction
---------------------------------------------
1         1             10            D         
2         1             21            D         
3        10             1             U         
4         1             5             D         
5         1            15             D
```

and a `Station` table with this data:

```
stn_id    stn_name
---------------------
1         Churchgate
2         Marine Lines
3         Charni Road
4         Grant Road
5         Mumbai Central
6         Mahalaxmi
7         Lower Parel
8         Elphinstone Road
9         Dadar
10        Matunga Road
11        Mahim
12        Bandra
13        Khar Road
14        Santacruz
15        Vile Parle
```

I want station name depending on the condition. If `strt_stn_id > end_stn_id`, I want station name of `end_stn_id` else station name of `strt_stn_id`.

So how to use if condition in a SQL query?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: my desired output is the stn_name depending on the condition

Comment: @ SWeko: I m using SQL Server database

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.*, S.stn_name
FROM Train T
INNER JOIN Station S
    ON  CASE WHEN T.strt_stn_id > T.end_stn_id 
        THEN T.end_stn_id ELSE T.strt_stn_id END = S.stn_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use `case`

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php

gives an example of how to use

```
    'station' = CASE
    WHEN (strt_stn_id > end_stn_id) THEN (end_stn_id)
    ELSE (strt_stn_id)
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can definitely put the logic in the `on` clause, I much prefer to do two separate joins and put the logic in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT T.*,
       (case when t.strt_stn_id > t.end_stn_id then starts.stn_name
             else ends.stn_name
        end) as TheName
FROM Train T INNER JOIN
     Station Starts
     ON T.strt_stn_id = Starts.stn_id inner join
     Station ends
     on T.end_stn_id = ends.stn_id
```

In general, a `case` statement or function all in an `on` clause prevents the engine from using indexes.  If the tables have reasonable indexes (such as on their primary keys), this version will work better.  As an aside, I also think having the logic in the `select` clause is more understandable, but I recognize that others might disagree.